# Convert Polygon Feature Centroid to Points using Python

Tags: python, shapefile

I would like to convert some polygon based shp files that have several polygon features into points for each feature that would essentially represent the centriod of each polygon feature.  I know in ArcGIS world I could use Feature To Point tool but I would like to keep this in a script that could be run on PC's that don't have arcpy on them so I'm looking for an open source alternative to that.  Is anyone aware of a library I could use for this along with some direction on how to leverage it accomplish this?

Comment: I'm still having multiple issues with the answer that Gene provided below.  The issues are how it's reorders the attributes from their original order to alphabetical which is a problem.  Secondly, the shape file get's corrupt possibly due to the file I'm trying to convert having over 250 attributes.

Comment: There is a standard tool called 'Polygon Centroids' in QGIS that does exactly this - do you require a script? It would be easy enough to script using PyQGIS I would think.

Comment: It needs to be a script and work on PC's that do not have QGIS on them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can run an `ogr2ogr` command (e.g. from a OSGeo4w Shell). E.g. on a shapefile of countries:

```
cd path/to/shapefiles
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT ST_Centroid(geometry), * FROM countries" -dialect sqlite countries_centroid.shp countries.shp
```

The new shapefile `countries_centroid.shp` should be similar to the input, but just contain one point per [Multi]Polygon.

@PEL also shows a good example with ST_PointOnSurface, which is simple to substitute in this command.

---

Something similar can be done in Python, if needed, but it may take a few lines of code more:

```
import os
from osgeo import ogr

ogr.UseExceptions()
os.chdir('path/to/shapefiles')

ds = ogr.Open('countries.shp')
ly = ds.ExecuteSQL('SELECT ST_Centroid(geometry), * FROM countries', dialect='sqlite')
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName('Esri shapefile')
ds2 = drv.CreateDataSource('countries_centroid.shp')
ds2.CopyLayer(ly, '')
ly = ds = ds2 = None  # save, close
```

Comment: I think you've proposed and simpliest solution with OGR and SQL. I think it's safer to add a parameter to OGR with -nlt Point

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get this to work.  I get an error claiming that ST_Centroid is not function.

Comment: It needs the SQLite dialect option (as shown) and Spatialite built into GDAL, which is not always guaranteed. OSGeo4W has a good version of GDAL that will run this command correctly.

Comment: I can get your top script within the ogr2ogr commend to work without issue.  However, I need to do this in a stand-alone python script so I'm trying to get your 2nd set of code to work which is where I continue to the ST_Centroid is not a function error.  My code is identical to what you have above including the sqlite dialect.

Comment: The error you describe is when GDAL was built without Spatialite support. Some gdal-python packages support this, but not all. Try opening an OSGeo4W shell and running the Python script from that environment. I think the default set of packages related to `gdal-bin` include this support.

Comment: @MikeT - The script does work when running from the OSGeo4W shell.  So now the mystery is how do I get the GDAL with Spatialite support so I can run outside of the OSGeo4W shell.  Any ideas where I can get the GDAL with Spatialite support without needing the OSGeo4W shell?  I installed the GDAL version I have from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and it's version 2.1.2.

Comment: @wilbev unfortunately @gohlke's libraries currently don't have Spatialite support, so you might want to `pip uninstall gdal`. A complete install of GDAL for (e.g.) C:\Python27 is from [GISInternals](http://www.gisinternals.com) . First, install the 'core' (e.g. `gdal-201-1500-x64-core.msi`), followed by the Python bindings (e.g. `GDAL-2.1.2.win-amd64-py2.7.msi`). This is much more complicated to install, and if you have problems, I suggest asking a new question along the lines of "How to install GDAL with Spatialite", required for a regular Python (non-OSGeo4W)

Comment: @Mike T - Thank you for your efforts so I awarded you the bounty.  I still don't have this working for me outside of OSGeo4W but I hope to at some point.  I'm now having trouble with getting GDAL installed using these msi files.  They install but I try to import the module and they don't import.

Answer (score 10):

Simply use [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) or [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/) (Python 2.7.x and 3.x)

Some polygons

[image]

```
import geopandas as gpd
# GeoDataFrame creation
poly = gpd.read_file("geoch_poly.shp")
poly.head()
```

[image]

Transformation to points (centroids)

```
# copy poly to new GeoDataFrame
points = poly.copy()
# change the geometry
points.geometry = points['geometry'].centroid
# same crs
points.crs =poly.crs
points.head()
```

[image]

```
# save the shapefile
points.to_file('geoch_centroid.shp')
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer gene.  I think you may have one typo above where the 'gdf' variable should be 'poly" right?  in the points.crs = gdf.crs code.  I'm also experiencing a couple of other issues where the .prj file is not getting created, it's showing up empty and the order of the attribute fields are changing their order from the polygon data since they seem to now be alphabetical.  It's important they stay in the same order.  You know of a way to keep the field attribute in same order?

Comment: Thanks, corrected.  For the order of the attributes fields, simply change the order of  the GeoPandas GeoDataFrame (= Pandas DataFrame)

Comment: Thanks Gene, but I'm not sure I understand where I would change that order in the code here.  I'm also running into two other issues with this.  First the *.prj file is blank on the new shp file.  Secondly, when I attempt to open the shp file in shp reader it gives an error opening the file like it is corrupt. It seems to work without getting corrupt if the shp file only has a single feature but multiples is where it's having trouble it seems.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to know  [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for that and I have no problem with the script with my data (I use the latest versions of GeoPandas, Fiona and Numpy)

Comment: I can send you the shp file so you can see for yourself but this shp file has over 250 columns of data that I imagine are creating problems for it.  I tried this on a shp file with much fewer attributes and it doesn't seem to have any trouble.

Comment: The fiona link is dead

Answer (score 5):

Another, perhaps more 'low level', way would be to directly use `fiona` and `shapely` for I/O and geometry processing.

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape, mapping

with fiona.open('input_shapefile.shp') as src:
    meta = src.meta
    meta['schema']['geometry'] = 'Point'
    with fiona.open('output_shapefile.shp', 'w', **meta) as dst:
        for f in src:
            centroid = shape(f['geometry']).centroid
            f['geometry'] = mapping(centroid)
            dst.write(f)
```

Comment: Thanks Loic.  That definitely fixes the sort issue I was having but it's not fixing the issue with so many attributes causing the file to become corrupt.  Would you have any other ideas on how to overcome that issue?  I guess I may need to delete attributes.  I can send you an example file if it would help.

Comment: @wilbev Send a download link to your data if you can. Otherwise I don't see what could be wrong.

Comment: Loic, I emailed you an example file.  Hopefully that gives you a good idea of the issue I'm running into.

Comment: @wilbev what do you mean by 'the file becomes corrupt'? Using the file you sent, I could produce the centroids and open the output shapefile in QGIS without problems. The attributes table remains unchanged between both files.

Comment: By corrupt, I mean it's essentially an empty dbf file since after i run the script it creates a 1 KB sized dbf file and when you open that it's completely empty.  If I run the same exact script, the one you list above, on a file with fewer attributes, it works without issue.  I even tried on a second PC and got the same result.  I don't get it.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you describe on my system. The attribute table is preserved when I run the script

Comment: Loic - Could you email me your converted file along with the exact script you use?  Maybe there is some subtle difference that is making my fail.  I can send you a new file and my script.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to use gdal/ogr Virtual Format. 
(http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html) and  SQL /SQLITE dialect (http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html and https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA/spatialite-sql-3.0.0.html)

My polygon shapefile is named poly.shp. Then I create this XML like file named vrt.vrt . Inside this file (vrt.vrt), here the content to convert to points

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="poly">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">poly.shp</SrcDataSource>
        <SrcSQL dialect="sqlite">SELECT ST_PointOnSurface(geometry) as geom_point, poly.* from poly</SrcSQL>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoints</GeometryType> 
        <GeometryField name="geom_point" />
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

At this time, you can integrate this file into Qgis to validate. For sure, the rendering is slower than the raw source because every feature is cast as point on every rendering query.

After, convert this file (vrt.vrt) into something else using gdal/ogr utils from a python shell/script

```
os.system("ogr2ogr point_from_vrt.shp vrt.vrt poly")
```

You get a point shapefile named point_from_vrt.shp .

Comment: I was able to get this to work but I would like to keep all of this within a python script since I need to convert 100's of files all with different file names.  I would like to use @Mike T solution but I get a "No such function: ST_Centroid if I use that and I also tried ST_PointOnSurface which also says there is no such function.  Any idea why it would be stating these are no functions of ExecuteSQL()?

Comment: I get `'wkbPoints' is not a valid value of the atomic type`