# ogr2ogr polygon to point with point inside the polygon

Tags: ogr, ogr2ogr, polygon-to-point

Can ogr2ogr be used to convert a polygon to a point but the point must remain inside the polygon? It does not matter where the point is as long as it is inside the object polygon.

Answer (score 6):

This is covered in [Convert Polygon Feature Centroid to Points using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216788/convert-polygon-feature-centroid-to-points-using-python), but if you don't know the SpatialLite operators it might not be clear which of the answers to use. `ST_Centroid` returns the centroid, which **may not be located in the shape**. `ST_PointOnSurface` returns a point that will always be somewhere inside in the shape.

```
cd path/to/shapefiles
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT ST_PointOnSurface(geometry), * FROM countries" -dialect sqlite countries_centroid.shp countries.shp
```